# Does Linq-to-Sqlite support dynamic table creation using Code First approach?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, sqlite

I am trying to run a demo app to do a POC on Linq-to-Sqlite. I'm using the latest System.Data.Sqlite NuGet package and .Net Framework 4.5 to create sample console application which will only create the database file initially. The code simply creates an object of Movie class and adds it to the DbSet property on the DbContext class. However, on SaveChanges(), i get a System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException with the message "no such table: Movie". Below is my code:

```
if (!File.Exists(_databaseFilePath))
    SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(_databaseFilePath);

using (var dbContext = new MovieAppContext())
{
    dbContext.Movies.Add(new Movie(1, "Titanic", 7.5));
    var retVal = dbContext.SaveChanges();
}

public class MovieAppContext : DbContext
{
    public MovieAppContext():base("MovieAppConStr")
    {

    }

    public MovieAppContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    { }

    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Chinook Database does not pluralize table names
        modelBuilder.Conventions
            .Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** So the question is, just like Linq-to-Sql, does Linq-to-Sqlite provider allow us to create tables in the database equivalent to the models created using the code-first approach ?

Comment: dude... you need a question.  What is your question?

Comment: Well, I'm sorry...i thought I asked a question in the question box with a question mark.

Comment: I don't understand the question because I believe "Code First" is an Entity Framework only term.  Is that what you are asking?  If so then no - you need entity framework.  But you have entity framework as a tag so you already know that.  I'm just not clear on the question.

Comment: probably yes Hogan. I was under the assumption that Linq-to-Sqlite can be implemented using the similar approaches used by Entity Framework. But thanks anyways, you and @ErikEJ removed my misconception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework Code First with SQLite only Works with an existing database, so no. There are alternative EF providers for sqlite that do support database creation with Code First... Devart for example